# Getting a specific id value for use

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I'm currently working on a friendshipsystem. To accept a friend I need to get the friendship_id value.

Based on the email (from the session) I can get a lot of information, such as surname, name, photo, ID NUMBER,... from the specific friendshiprequest

I can print the information for each friendship in this way. So I have the FRIENDSHIP ID VALUE TO DISPLAY AS INFORMATION but now I want to use it in a function.

```
$friendrequests=$friendship->GetAllFriendRequests($email);

<?php
    foreach ($friendrequests as $request) {
    echo "
        <div><p>
            <a href='profile.php?user_id=".$request['friendship_applicant_id'] . "'>
                <img src='uploads/" . $request['friendship_applicant_avatar']  . " " . " ' alt='' />" . $request['friendship_applicant_surname'] . $request['friendship_id'] . " " . $request['friendship_applicant_name'] . "
            </a> has send you a friend request" . "

            <form action='" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "' method='post'>
                <button type='submit' name=''>Accept</button>
                <button type='submit' name=''>Decline</button>
            </form>
        </p></div>";   
}
                    ?>
```

So i tried to get the specific number with the following code, but it says undefined index for friendship_id: `$friendrequestnumber = $friendrequests['friendship_id'];`

This is the code the GetAllFriendRequests function. Can I use this code or should I do it in a totally different way?

```
public function GetAllFriendRequests($email) {
    $db = new Db();

    $select = "SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE friendship_recipient = '" . $email . "' AND friendship_status = 'pending' ORDER BY friendship_id DESC";

    $result = $db -> conn -> query($select);

    $result_array=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $result_array[]=$row;                                                                                          
    }
    return $result_array;

}
```

With a var_dump I get this information of the 2 requests:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 84 [friendship_id] => 84 [1] => ron@hot.com [friendship_applicant] => ron@hot.com [2] => 29 [friendship_applicant_id] => 29 [3] => ron [friendship_applicant_name] => ron [4] => ron [friendship_applicant_surname] => ron [5] => 1394134610fuckyou.jpg [friendship_applicant_avatar] => 1394134610fuckyou.jpg [6] => jan@hot.com [friendship_recipient] => jan@hot.com [7] => 1 [friendship_recipient_id] => 1 [8] => Vandenbergh [friendship_recipient_name] => Vandenbergh [9] => Jan [friendship_recipient_surname] => Jan [10] => 1394041001fuckyou.jpg [friendship_recipient_avatar] => 1394041001fuckyou.jpg [11] => Pending [friendship_status] => Pending [12] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [friendship_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 78 [friendship_id] => 78 [1] => Bert@hot.com [friendship_applicant] => Bert@hot.com [2] => 2 [friendship_applicant_id] => 2 [3] => Van Damme [friendship_applicant_name] => Van Damme [4] => Bert [friendship_applicant_surname] => Bert [5] => sdfds.png [friendship_applicant_avatar] => sdfds.png [6] => Jan@hot.com [friendship_recipient] => Jan@hot.com [7] => 1 [friendship_recipient_id] => 1 [8] => Vandenbergh [friendship_recipient_name] => Vandenbergh [9] => Jan [friendship_recipient_surname] => Jan [10] => 1394041001fuckyou.jpg [friendship_recipient_avatar] => 1394041001fuckyou.jpg [11] => Pending [friendship_status] => Pending [12] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [friendship_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) )
```

Comment: Where do you want to get this ID? In or outside the foreach loop?

Comment: outside, i want to use it in a function to update a friendship relation 

$friendship ->AcceptFriendRequest($number);

the number has to be the friendship_id

Comment: Look at your var_dumped string (you have a multidimensional array) ... you'll have to use something like this: `$friendrequests[0]["friendship_id"]` .. and you have to find a way on how to find out if it's "0", "4" or "123456" ... by looping through the complete array again or use some filter/search function on it!

Comment: $friendrequests[0]["friendship_id"] gives me the first friendship (friendship_id = 84)... indeed, but what if the updated friendship_id must be 78? In my example 78 is the 2nd in row

Answer (score 1):

From your var_dump, `$friendrequests` is a nested array. So you need to use a loop to iterate over all values like in the case above where `$request['friendship_id']` can use it or if you simply want the first value, use `$friendrequests[0]['friendship_id']`

Comment: @djot Sorry didn't see it uptil now

Comment: Unfortunately you can flag a lot of bullsh*t here at SO but not the real important things ... ;)